# Font Size variable not working Wezterm LUA file

Tags: linux, lua

I am running Garuda Linux with xfce and Wezterm as my terminal emulator.  Currently I am customizing the lua file for Wezterm, but have run into some issues.

Wezterm is ignoring the font size I use, regardless of the number I input.  In addition, it is ignoring the line that should disable the audible bell.

I have read through the documentation, but I am unable to discover what I have done wrong.  Any help would be appreciated be it a solution or the page that contains the solution.

```
local config = {}
font_size = 50.0


local cfg_misc = {
    window_close_confirmation = "NeverPrompt",
    automatically_reload_config = false,
    
    -- Disable all noises
        audible_bell = "Disabled",
}

config.colors = {
    --Default text color
    foreground = '#00ff00',
    --Default Background color
    background = '#000000',

    --Override the  cell background color when current cell is occupied by 
    --the cursor and the cursor style is set to Block
    cursor_bg = '#00ff00',
    --Overrides the text color when the current cell is occupied by the 
    --cursor
    cursor_fg = '#000000',

    --Background color for selected text
    selection_bg = '#00ff00',
    --Foreground color for selected text
    selection_fg = '#000000'
}
--This is on line number 32
config.font = 
  wezterm.font( 'Classic Console Neue' )


return config
'''
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

I've faced the same problem before. Here is the solution:

Font Size is not working because you've chosen an undefined font for the WezTerm, you can try this setting just for the test:

```
config.font = wezterm.font 'JetBrains Mono'
config.font_size = 21
```

## Not Happy With The Default Fonts?

WezTerm bundles JetBrains Mono, Nerd Font Symbols, and Noto Color Emoji fonts and uses those for the default font configuration.

If you wish to use a different font face, then you can use the wezterm.font function to specify it.

```
config.font = wezterm.font 'Fira Code'
-- You can specify some parameters to influence the font selection;
-- for example, this selects a Bold, Italic font variant.
config.font =
  wezterm.font('JetBrains Mono', { weight = 'Bold', italic = true })
```

## Available Fonts

Using the command below you can list all available fonts in your system, and see how to use them in the wezterm.font method:

```
wezterm ls-fonts --list-system
```

Wow, the result is really useful!

## Fallback Scenario?

WezTerm allows specifying an ordered list of fonts; when resolving text into glyphs the first font in the list is consulted, and if the glyph isn't present in that font, WezTerm proceeds to the next font in the fallback list.

The default fallback includes the popular Nerd Font Symbols font, which means that you don't need to use specially patched fonts to use the powerline or Nerd Fonts symbol glyphs.

You can specify your own fallback; that's useful if you've got a killer monospace font, but it doesn't have glyphs for the Asian script that you sometimes work with:

```
config.font = wezterm.font_with_fallback {
  'Fira Code',
  'DengXian',
}
```

WezTerm will still append its default fallback to whatever list you specify, so you needn't worry about replicating that list if you set your own fallback.

If none of the fonts in the fallback list (including WezTerm's default fallback list) contain a given glyph, then wezterm will resolve the system fallback list and try those fonts too. If a glyph cannot be resolved, wezterm will render a special "Last Resort" glyph as a placeholder. You may notice the placeholder appear momentarily and then refresh itself to the system fallback glyph on some systems.

I hope it will fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since WezTerm is going to understand and read config through the `local config` you have created and returned inside `.wezterm.lua` file, just simply do this one `config.font_size = 50.0`. make sure you are doing `config.font_size - 50.0` after declaring `local config` and before `return config`